# Heroku push failed with weird error message

Tags: django, heroku

I've had a Django app running on Heroku for a while now.

Couldn't find this error online when it came up:

```
$ git push heroku master
...
remote: -----> Uninstalling stale dependencies
...
remote:      $ pip install -r requirements.txt
remote: 
remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        66 static files copied to '/tmp/build_2271dc3bd9820ee9e10847bbab5f6b47/xxx/staticfiles', 66 post-processed.
remote: 
remote: mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/app/.heroku/src’ to ‘/tmp/build_2271dc3bd9820ee9e10847bbab5f6b47/.heroku/src’; unable to remove target: Is a directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/....git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxx.git'
$
```

I tried running `git push heroku +master` also and that didn't work either.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
Looks like this was probably a bug on Heroku's part because it just resolved itself for myself and @Wei at the same time.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I just deployed a version 2 hours ago and it went just fine, but now I'm getting the 'mv: inter-device move failed'. Here's the full output (same as @michaelsnowden): `remote: mv: inter-device move failed: ‘/app/.heroku/src’ to ‘/tmp/build_xxxxx/.heroku/src’; unable to remove target: Is a directory
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to my-app-name.`

Comment: having the same problem too as of 15 min ago

Comment: Seems to have resolved itself for me now.

Comment: @Wei same. must've been a temporary bug on their side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the Heroku team was updating some stuff and damaged the python buildpack.

- I'm pretty sure it was in this commit --> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/1a1cedfc2153f12828f92ebc76997a172fec9451
- And a few hours later they fixed it --> https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/commit/4e8c469ec73fbbb44e0d36002ed88a281afd79c0.

In the meantime, a few developers went crazy trying to figure out what the h*** happened (myself included).